# GSON serializtion not returning the right json string

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to serialize an object of this format with GSON

[image: Object structure]

Here is my code:

```
public String encode(Object object){
    return this.gson.toJson(object);
}
```

The problem is here is the result I get:

```
"m_Volume": 57056040
```

as opposed to what I was expecting:

```
"m_Volume": {
  "m_Exponent": 0,
  "m_Mantissa": [4, 3, 102, -101, 40]
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @YogenRai that function is called multiple times, so i cannot pass in a specific object type, hence the generic Object class

Comment: Can you tell why you are expecting what you are expecting? What is the object you pass to `encode(..)` in this case? Can you share the code for that class?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a custom object named `XempBigDecimal`

Maybe instead of:

```
public String encode(Object object){
    return this.gson.toJson(object);
}
```

try to pass a concrete type:

```
public String encode(XempBigDecimal object){
    return this.gson.toJson(object);
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to reproduce your case via unit test as follows:

```
public class GsonTest {

  private Gson gson;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    gson = new Gson();
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldCreateJson() {
    XempBigDecimal object = new XempBigDecimal(new m_Volume(0, new byte[] {4, 3, 102, -101, 40}));

    String json = encode(object);

    assertThat(json).isEqualTo("{\"m_Volume\":{\"m_Exponent\":0,\"m_Mantissa\":[4,3,102,-101,40]}}");
  }

  public String encode(Object object) {
    return gson.toJson(object);
  }

  public String encodeType(XempBigDecimal object) {
    return gson.toJson(object);
  }

  private class XempBigDecimal {
    public XempBigDecimal(GsonTest.m_Volume m_Volume) {
      this.m_Volume = m_Volume;
    }

    private m_Volume m_Volume;
  }

  private class m_Volume {
    public m_Volume(int m_Exponent, byte[] m_Mantissa) {
      this.m_Exponent = m_Exponent;
      this.m_Mantissa = m_Mantissa;
    }

    private int m_Exponent;
    private byte[] m_Mantissa;
  }
}
```

and this test passes, so probably defining a parameter as an `Object` type is not an issue. Maybe there's something wrong with your object or class definition? Maybe `m_Exponent` and `m_Mantissa` are ignored by Gson? It may happen when they're followed by the `transient` keyword.

Comment: I cannot do that in this case, the encode method is used by different objects. If you think this will solve the problem I will try to investigate further with your solution.

Comment: Can you create separate methods for different types?

Comment: @ piotr.wittchen it's not efficient, but again do you think that is what is causing the problem?

Comment: @WaleA. I've updated my answer. Probably passing `Object` type is not the source of the problem. I've provided other suggestions.

Comment: I dont have the transient keyword on any of the properties. But thank you for writing a test case. I'll keep digging